# How to do mobile application monitoring?

Tags: mobile, monitoring, graphite, health-monitoring

I want to be able to monitor issues from mobile application like from backend micro-services.
I'm not aware of any real time monitoring for mobile applications outside.

I think that it can really help to monitor mobile application and report errors from the application and not only from the backend services. Sometimes the application is connected to multiple services and has its own logic so it seems like one place to catch all errors and wrong behaviour.

1. Are there any tools outside?
2. If for example I'll use mParticle/Segment as Hub to report events, can I connect it to Graphite somehow which is push-based monitoring ? Maybe through SQS / AWS Lambda ? 
   https://www.mparticle.com/integrations

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes it's possible to send data to Graphite using a combination of SQS + Lambda. I've tested this by writing some metric data to SQS and used a node js lambda function to read and forward that data to our carbon endpoint at https://hostedgraphite.com via UDP per our language guide [here](https://www.hostedgraphite.com/docs/languageguide/lg_nodejs.html?utm_source=sof&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=graphite)

Having said that, there are some further considerations that we must take in order to ensure this works: the main one being data format. Graphite/Carbon require data in a specific format, something that mParticle might not support directly. As such, you will need an AWS Lambda that formats the messages and then forwards to Graphite (or optionally, to another SQS queue where another Lambda reads and forwards that data to Graphite).